# How to set url/file loaders to import the locally generated fonts using webpack?

Tags: webpack-2

I'm using webpack 2 to generate a project using the following loaders:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            import: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[local]',
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: postcssOptions,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      test: /\.woff2?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          publicPath: '/assets/',
          mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          publicPath: '/assets/',
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: '/assets/'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'image/svg+xml'
        }
      }
    }
  ],
},
```

In my `index.css` I have the following imports which target to local files except the one using google fonts.

```
/* Local imports */
@import 'vendor/colors';
@import 'vendor/normalize';
@import 'vendor/highlight/zenburn';

/* Webfonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700|Raleway:400,700|Yellowtail');
```

As a result of a project build I got the following assets generated:

```
Hash: ce740f17c03a9b6a2685
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 24103ms
                                 Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot    166 kB          [emitted]
af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2   77.2 kB          [emitted]
 fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff     98 kB          [emitted]
  b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf    166 kB          [emitted]
  912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg    444 kB          [emitted]  [big]
                                app.js   26.3 kB       0  [emitted]         app
                            styles.css    5.3 kB       0  [emitted]         app
                            app.map.js  87 bytes    0, 0  [emitted]         app, app
```

As you can see there are five generated font files but in my generated styles.css file I keep getting the reference to the google fonts url:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700|Raleway:400,700|Yellowtail);`
```

How can I make to target the locally generated files instead of the external URL?